# Rename form and all instances of form in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a project in Visual Studio 2010 and want to rename a form and all instances of a form via the Solution Explorer. Here is what my screen looks like:
[image]

Any ideas? I just need a quick way to rename them all at once. I know I can rename them individually but I'm trying to find an easier way so I can do it faster.

Comment: The name of the *file* does not have anything to do whatsoever with the name of the "instances".  If you want to rename a type then simply use Refactor > Rename in the text editor context menu when you right-click the type name.

Answer (score 1):

In VS, renaming the form.cs file should also rename the form's resource and designer definition file automatically. If it is not doing that then you might have changes something manually.